# Spring Boot OAuth2 with JDBC Using Custom UserDetailService

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I am trying to secure my Spring Boot Rest API using OAuth2.0 with Spring security and want to store OAuth tokens (Access Token and Refresh Token) in JDBC database.
For Username and Password validation i have created CustomUserDetailService.

**I am getting following error-**

```
{
  "timestamp": 1480042650103,
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "path": "/oauth/token"
}
```

My Code is -

**Oauth2Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;


        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2ServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

        @Bean
        public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
            return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
            security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .approvalStoreDisabled()
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                .jdbc(dataSource);
        }

    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {  
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetailService**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService 
    implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // I tested this logic and works fine so i avoid this lines
        return userDetailsService;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=my-trusted-client
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=secret
security.oauth2.client.authorized-grant-types=password,refresh_token,authorization_code,implicit
security.oauth2.client.scope=read,write,trust
security.oauth2.client.resource-ids=oauth2-resource
security.oauth2.client.access-token-validity-seconds=120
security.oauth2.client.refresh-token-validity-seconds=600
```

Please suggest me how can i solve this error ??

Comment: Did you insert any data in the database?